# JFrame reloads initial content on mouse over

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I have a `JPanel` with a `GridLayout(1,0)` set to a `JFrame` `Borderlayout.SOUTH`, there are placed a couple of buttons in here (when pressed they change a variables value to the index of the created button).

Everything is added correctly, but when I try to update the `JPanel` it does work at first (only when window is maximized). But then when I go over a button (or all the buttons) it goes back to what the original content of the panel.

I've tried `invalidate`, `validate`, `repaint`, `jframe.setvisible(true)` - none of these seem to work properly.

Any ideas?

```
 private void toonHand(){
        JPanel pnlSouth = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
        JButton[] btnArr =new JButton[50];
        ArrayList<Kaart> Thand=uno.getSpeler(0).getHand();
        for(int i=0;i<Thand.size();i++){
            final int T=i;
            btnArr[i]=new JButton();
            btnArr[i].setIcon(Thand.get(i).getImg());
            btnArr[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    iKaart=T;
                }
            });
            pnlSouth.add(btnArr[i]);
        }
        Hoofdvenster.remove(pnlSouth);
        Hoofdvenster.add(pnlSouth, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
```

Comment: *"I've tried.."*  Try posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - *"jframe.setvisible(true) - none of these seem to work properly."*  The last one is not spelled (or at least capitalized) correctly.  Please take more care when typing class, method & attribute names in questions.  These are technical forums, and it is already hard enough to solve theses things remotely, without the added difficulty of guessing what members are being referred to.

Comment: kind of hard since i'm working with multiple objects, pictures, and arrays from before mentioned objects...

Comment: If it could help you understand; this is some code for making the card game uno. all This should do is create a number of buttons (the same amount as you have cards in your hand) and when you press the button a private variable is changed to the value equal to the index of the button.

Comment: *"with multiple objects,"* Declare extra classes as 'default' access in the same source as the public class.  (1) *"pictures,"* Hot-link, grab them from the JRE, or generate them in code.  (1) *"and arrays"* Are you really saying this problem cannot be reproduced with 1 (or 0) arrays?  Even if so, 2-3 short arrays can be included in one SSCCE.  1) ***As mentioned in the SSCCE document which you have apparently either not read, or not understood.***

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: well i'm sorry that i'm stil a student and not up to your expectations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was just removing the panel, changing the content and adding it again.
Apparently this was giving some issues with displaying the content.
I fixed it by putting the panels as global variables, and splitting up the making and updating of the panels. So in every update i remove the panel, make the panel a new Panel and then i make it again.